# write multiple images to a file name and path

Tags: python, image, revit

I'm trying to create a script in dynamo for Revit using iron python,that takes multiple inputs of data i.e IN[0],creates and  saves the data as separate image  in a directory.  it worked when the input was text how could i make this into a function ?

This is what I have so far.I worked with one input as a code block

```
import clr
import sys
import System
from System import Array
from System.Collections.Generic import *
pyt_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib'
sys.path.append(pyt_path)
import os
#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variable.
dataEnteringNode = IN
FileName = IN[0]
FileDirectory = IN[1]
Image =  IN[2]
completeName = os.path.join(FileDirectory,FileName+".png")  
file = open(completeName,"w")
tofile = Image
file.write(tofile)
file.close()
out=0
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: You have to decide on your design.  Do you just want to open the file once then write to it in the function, or do you need to open and close the file in the function?  In the later case just use "append" mode.  You might wish to use binary mode as well.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: the script wont create separate images, i think its due to the fact that there are multiple In[0] and in a list format. I would like the script to save all the images from the list.